Quel adjectif concerne la femme de façon similaire à l'adjectif « marital » qui concerne le mari ?
L'adjectif « marital » concerne le mari dans un couple marié. Il est naturel de se demander : quel adjectif concerne la femme dans un couple marié ?

Dans l'expression "vie maritale", l'adjectif concerne les 2 sexes. Il est plus lié au mariage qu'au mari (cf cntrl).

@Graffito La question ne parle pas de « vie maritale » mais oppose « ce qui concerne le mari » pour lequel il existe marital (« consentement marital ») à « ce qui concerne la femme » dans un couple.  Le TLF (ton lien), comme la plupart des dictionnaires d'ailleurs, souligne bien que le premier sens de marital en français est « qui concerne le mari », le sens de « qui concerne le mariage » est d'ailleurs relativement récent (20e s.).

Il serait intéressant qu'on donne ici un exemple du mot dans une vraie phrase.

Uxorial? Fr.wkt ne connaît pas, yaka l'inventer, sur le modèle de l'anglais:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uxorial#Adjective

Relatif à l'épouse ou à son héritage, son cousinage etc.

Pour l'explication de cette lacune, vide: "Loi Salique", § "conséquences cocasses", je suppose.
Le sens que je propose est d'autant plus facile à deviner que fr.wkt connaît uxorien.
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/uxorien

Relatif à la descendance de l'épouse.

De ce que je comprends du commentaire de @None, il devrait être clair à la première lecture que les deux adjectifs n'ont pas le même sens et qu'un emprunt à l'anglais est nécessaire.

La piste uxor parait appropriée mais l'explication par « tout le monde devrait comprendre » ne me satisfait guère (un peu méprisante ?).  De surcroit citer wiktionary comme seule référence me parait un peu léger.  + une référence c'est que « uxorien » figure encre dans le Littré, même si le mot n'est plus guère employé,  et  la racine latine uxor n'a pas tout disparu en français. « Uxorilocal », réservé  à un jargon spécialisé est dans le Robert. « Uxoricide » monte dans les médias.

Je ne connais pas d'équivalent. Le terme marital est généralement employé avec une connotation juridique, et en France le code Napoléon (1804) donnait à l'épouse un statut de mineure. L’article 213 indiquait ainsi que le mari devait protection à sa femme, et la femme obéissance à son mari (ref.).
Je pense que l'on peut utiliser conjugal ou matrimonial qui s'appliquent au couple.

Clairement la question ne porte pas sur le sens de marital qui « concerne le couple » mais dans le sens de marital qui « concerne le mari ». Comme dans la phrase « jusqu'à la loi du 13 juillet 1965 les femmes avait besoin du consentement marital pour ouvrir un compte en banque.  »

@None: c'est pourquoi j'ai commencé par je ne connais pas d'équivalent. Je ne connais pas d'adjectif signifiant qui concerne l'épouse.
